# How do I change the layout and contents of a component dynamically in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, layout, dynamic, angular5

I am developing a **multi user web app using Angular and Laravel**.Basically it is an `Angular app` which will communicate with the backend through `Laravel API`.

1.First - I want to **change the layout of the components based on the user type/role** .

2.Second - I want to **change the content of the component based on each user**.

Currently all the components are developed and designed based on the **admin user**.

I am new to Angular.We are currently using Angular 5.
Which is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: This post may help: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/

Comment: @DeborahK ok Thank you..

Comment: You mentioned that you are new to Angular. Very few of the techniques in that article would fit into the category of "beginner". :-)